# Windows Phone PEM File Sign Request and Response

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am working on a corporate project. They sent me a .pem file. It has a private key. At this point, i do not know how can i get secure request and response with this rsa key.

This project is developed for windows phone 8.0 silverlight. I googled a lot but have only nothing. Webclient was used for provide connection between app and web server.

Any idea?